# Can single Main page contain multiple sub page instaces each containg ng-upload components?

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck in situation where I have a Main html & js files which includes same Sub page (html & js) containing ng-upload component two times.

In Main page's controller I have defined different javascript filename arrays to both ng-included Sub pages instances. To Sub page's controller I pass an argument in ng-include directive so, that Sub page's controller should know witch filename array it should be using.

I have also $watch for both Main page's filename arrays in sub page's controller because all added files are copied and uploaded from sub page's controller.

There is also a Servlet which moves file content from ng-upload from Sub page to BackEnd.

Problem is that when updating one Upload component in Main page it also updates second Upload component's file list. I have tried to avoid that using different javascript filename arrays.

But I want to know is that can I use same Sub page containing ng-upload directive using ng-include directives in Main page? Is that allowed?

I would not like to write two all most same kind of Sub pages / Controllers to get this issue to work.

Has anyone of you used same instance of Sub page/controller in Main page and succesfully handling upload from each Sub page?

An example would be great,

Best Regards,
Michael

Comment: It's allowed. please show your code or a plunker.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I can't get source for that code because it's quite large project, But are there any samples or something else around that could help? Br Michael

Comment: Your problem could be caused by so much reasons. Obviously it's a scope issue ( maybe you bind to a primitive , [read more](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)) but also I cannot understand how your controllers and files are structured. Maybe you can post only the related parts of the code.

Comment: Actually I passed parameters from Main page using ng-repeat in ng-include. I passed an Object containing all data and parameters for both cases and that solved the whole problem.